# Launch the same activity from both app launcher and notification when foreground service is running

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin, xamarin.android

My setup is the following:

- Activity A (launched on initial app launch)
- Activity B (starts a foreground service to records GPS data)

When the foreground service is started, I create a pending intent for the notification, and upon tapping it, Activity B is opened, which is the expected outcome.

While the foreground service is running, if I launch the app from the app launcher, it opens Activity A. Here, when the service is running, I need to launch Activity B.

Comment: Can you show us some code please? What does your Manifest look like? How do you call the activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be putting variable into SharedPreferences to indicate if the service is running and check it in your ActivityA. If service is running don't load any views and open ActivityB.